# Mountain Lion screen crashes after returning from sleep

Tags: macos, graphics-card, crash, osx-mountain-lion

During the past 3 days I have experienced the following issue: when returning from sleep, I see an extremely garbled version of my desktop. The only thing that seems to help is a reboot.

My first guess is that this is related to the video card. After looking into this issue, I found a lot of problems related to ML and returning from sleep, such as [this post on AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59859/how-to-stop-macbook-pro-retina-from-freezing-locking-at-the-login-authenticati), but I think this is a different issue because it does not speak of a garbled screen.

**Some more details:**

- System: MacBook Pro 15" early 2011, 2,2GHZ I7, 8GB Ram, AMD Radeon HD6750M 1024
- The issue seems to happen only when I open my laptop in the morning; if I close and open my laptop during the day, it does not seem to happen.
- The issue 'solves' when rebooting.

**Photo of how this looks:**

[image: Photograph of a 2011 MacBook Pro with a garbled screen]

**Update November 27th 2012:**

I re-installed my laptop a couple of weeks ago, which seemed to have solved the problem, but sadly, it still persists.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue as well. The exact same pattern on the screen. Mine seems to happen after disconnecting from a thunderbolt display.

Comment: I 'solved' this issue by doing a clean install of Mountain Lion. I won't add this as an answer through, since it does not actually explain the issue.

Comment: @cpatrick sadly, I am once again getting the crashes now. Have you have had any luck?

Comment: I haven't seen it for a while, but I didn't do anything to fix it. :(